# IAM policy to allow users to disable only their own MFA device with API/CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, multi-factor-authentication

I want to enable MFA in an AWS organization and allow users to manage only their own MFA device. But I want the users to be able to manage the device via the API/CLI (and not using the AWS Console).

I found [this policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_delegate-permissions_examples.html#creds-policies-mfa-console) in the AWS documentation, which is almost good, as it allow to create/enable/delete its own MFAdevice:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUsersToCreateEnableResyncDeleteTheirOwnVirtualMFADevice",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:mfa/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUsersToDeactivateTheirOwnVirtualMFADevice",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:DeactivateMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:mfa/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, for device desactivation (`iam:DeactivateMFADevice`), it requires the condition `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent` to be `true`. This is a sound security measure, the user can not disable MFA, without using MFA. But in this policy, when logged with MFA via API/CLI using STS and assuming a role, the resource `"arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:mfa/${aws:username}"` does not represent the actual resource, as `${aws:username}` [is not present](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse). I suppose that when using the AWS Console as a user, the boolean `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent` can be true. But as far as I know, with API/CLI it is not possible to have both `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent==true` and `${aws:username}` present.

So, what policy could I write to authorize only the users to disable their device when using MFA, but when they assume a role ?

[disclaimer, this is to be used with the [awless](https://github.com/wallix/awless) CLI]

Comment: This is not possible as the APIs work in same way in Console/CLI/SDK. You can use the aws:UserAgent condition key but that can be modified in a browser. Not sure why you are calling sts:assumerole. If you want MultiFactorAuthPresent should be true, you can use get-session-token.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use `get-session-token`. I did not use this call, because it is not officially supported in the `aws-sdk-go` as a credential provider, and [there is no standard way](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/1370) to store it in `~/.aws/config`. But indeed, that must be the only way to solve my problem.